# HTML email conditional statement for Apple mail

Tags: css, html-email, conditional-statements, apple-mail

Hello fellow programmers

Currently i have been working on creating some email newsletters, and i have experienced some errors, which only occur in Apple Mail 5. As i have already used conditional statements for targeting Outlook specifically, i was wondering if the same was possible with Apple Mail 5 ?

FYI: Apple Mail 6 works like a charm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no Apple 5 conditional statement, however there is usually an alternative method to doing most things code-wise.

Outlook conditionals aside, the only things you have to play with are the style sheet css (ignored by Gmail etc) and media queries (able to target specific devices).

Comment: Thanks for clearing that out for me. I couldn't seem to find anything on the subject on google, believe it or not.

Comment: That usually means it doesn't exist! :)

Comment: I just wanted to be 100% certain :)

Answer (score 4):

You can't use conditional code to target Apple Mail, but it does render media queries.

So you could use something like this to target Apple Mail:

```
<style type="text/css">
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 601px) {
.style {color: #666666!important;}
}
</style>
```

This would target only those devices that can display the full-with email AND media queries (which, at present, is a grand total of one client: Apple Mail).